render SVG vector image files in DirectX 11
I need to render SVG vector image files (static images and animation) on DirectX 11. Is there a way to do this, or I have to convert SVG to a DirectX 11 compatible format file?

NOTE: I don't have a problem if I have to working with XML directly, and I use DirectX SDK 2010.


You can use Direct2D, D2D1DeviceContext5::CreateSvgDocument method, etc. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/d2d1_3/nf-d2d1_3-id2d1devicecontext5-createsvgdocument however I don't think it supports animated SVG. Experience also demonstrates some rendering limitations but they are not documented.

The function is in d2d1_3.h, Is there other way for d2d1.h?

Not sure what you mean by that?

I mean the website you sent me states that the method ID2D1DeviceContext5::CreateSvgDocument is located in the header file d2d1_3.h. But I'm using the header file d2d1.h. Is there another way to render SVG in d2d1.h instead of using d2d1_3.h?

No, you must use d2d1_3.h. From the header ID2D1DeviceContext5 requires NTDDI_WIN10_RS1 (=> Windows 10 1607 "Redstone 1" https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog/using-the-windows-headers, aka "Windows 10 Anniversary Update", released in august 2016)

I really appreciate the help, but unfortunately, this doesn't solve my problem. I specifically need the d2d1.h header file since I'm using DirectX SDK 2010.

So, there's nothing builtin in Windows do do that.
